# Tab container Issue after updating AjaxControlToolkit from 15.1 to 16.1

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

Tab container Issue after updating AjaxControlToolkit from 15.1 to 16.1

All tabs remain disabled after selected once.

[ACTIVE TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKjTO.png)

CssClass for active tab: div.ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_disabled .ajax__tab_tab

Answer (score 0):

I found several articles addressing the latest update issues, but none of the "work arounds" worked for me. I also tried changing the csstheme of the container to none as suggested in one of the articles but that only made the tabs display separate to the left of the container.

The only solution I found that worked was to revert back to the previous version (15.1.3) of Ajax Control Toolkit (see picture of reverted versions tabs)
[image: Tabs in previous version]

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: I have found from past experience with Ajax Toolkit updates that you should NEVER update Ajax Control Toolkit on a production server until you have tested the update on a development server. Fortunately I was working on a development server and not the production server. :)